# using pattern attribute to validate value against a list of names

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, constraints

Is there anyway to validate an input value against a data list on client-side using pattern attribute?

for example I have an input of username and the username must be unique.

my value is

```
"John_Doe"
```

and must be validated against

```
[david,hello,dreamer,John_Doe,socceroos]
```

and it returns the form.formValidity() as false when the validation fails to fulfill the requirement?!

```
<input type="text" name="username"
 patern="?????">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) can accept a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). In this case separate the names with "pipe" (`|`) which denotes "or".

```css
input:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="username"
  pattern="^(?!(david|hello|dreamer|John_Doe|socceroos)$)(\w*)"
>
```

Comment: Not like that! I want it to return invalid if the new username is included on that list so that make sure that username is unique!

Comment: Updated. & don't bark orders at people.

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive mate!
 it was not helpful though in the first place! but now is. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp alternatives:

```
pattern="david|hello|dreamer|John_Doe|socceroos"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a regex to validate my username. I have no idea if it's standard or not! But working very well for me:
first, when you send a get request, you need to get all your usernames and make a touchups and then pass your currentUsername variable defined on your controller to be used on your html file using `ejs` npm:

```
for (let i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    usernames[i] = ("^" + usernames[i] + "$|");
    if (i === usernames.length - 1) {
        usernames[i] = usernames[i].slice(0, -1)
    }
};
const currentUsernames = usernames.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

And use the following pattern as your element attribute:

```
patern="(?!<%= currentUsernames %>).*"
```